# Integration by parts

Tags: integration, hyperbolic-functions

Question 2)b) part (ii) is the section that I'm having trouble with:

[image: Question]

I don't understand the method used in the solutions; how would you deduce the first line or is that something you should know?

[image: Solution]

Comment: There's a reason why LaTeX formatting is used on the site - it's a lot easier to understand than going through someone else's handwriting, parts of which are probably irrelevant.

Comment: I understand but I didn't think this was that hard to read and I doubt any of it is irrelevant, considering it's the official solution from the mark scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $$\frac{d\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}{dx}=\frac1{x+\sqrt{x^2+1}}\left(1+\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)=\frac1{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$$

Now using [Integration by parts formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts): $\int uvdx=u\int v dx-\left(\frac{du}{dx}\int vdx\right)dx$,

$$\int \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\cdot 1 dx$$
$$=\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\int dx-\left(\frac{d\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})}{dx}\int dx\right)dx$$
$$=x\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})-\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} dx$$

Now, put $x^2+1=y^2$ in the last integral

So, $ xdx=ydy$ $$\int \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} dx=\int\frac{ydy}y=y+c=\sqrt{x^2+1}+c$$ where $c$ is the arbitrary  constant for indefinite integral.

Comment: Sorry, how did you get to the second line? And is that dx supposed to be there?

Comment: @Mathlete, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts

Comment: Thanks, I'm familiar with the method but a few more brackets wouldn't have gone amiss. I can see it now.

Comment: @Mathlete, please find the edited answer.